# i am using flatList in react native to list data from server

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using a FlatList to fetch data from the server, but some of the content within the views is larger than the others, causing too much space around them. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

this is part of my code:

```
<FlatList
        data={listOfOrders}
        renderItem={({item, index}) =>
          item.visible === true && (
            <Order
              handleItemClick={handleItemClick}
              colorDivChanger={colorDivChanger}
              item={item}
              selectedCheckIcon={selectedCheckIcon}
              index={index}
              blueColor={blueColor}
              handleOrderClick={handleOrderClick}
              windowWidth={windowWidth}
              porukaOperateru={porukaOperateru}
              listOfOrders={listOfOrders}
              setListOfOrders={setListOfOrders}
            />
          )
        }
        keyExtractor={item => item.idNaloga.toString()}
        numColumns={numC}
        contentContainerStyle={orderStyleSheet.container}
      />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNRSo.png)

i was trying to fill this gaps around the big order , but isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Try to add columnWrapperStyle to your flatlist:

```
<FlatList
  data={listOfOrders}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
    item.visible === true && (
      <Order
        // other props of your component
      />
    )
  }
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.idNaloga.toString()}
  numColumns={numC}
  contentContainerStyle={orderStyleSheet.container}
  columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
/>
```